# add proxy model to update existing data using django

Tags: django, proxy, model

I am trying this but I don't seem to be able to select an existing row from the parent model before creating proxy model

```
from django_mail_admin.models import Mailbox, OutgoingEmail, IncomingEmail
from core.models import User


class MailboxProxy(Mailbox):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class OutgoingEmailProxy(OutgoingEmail):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class IncomingEmailProxy(IncomingEmail):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```